# Laravel 5.4 (1/1) TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, token, laravel-5.4

Localmente todos os formulários funcionam, porém quando coloquei online está dando `erro` como se não tivesse o `_token` atribuido aos `forms`.

```
APP_NAME=MonkStudio
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:KV/4jmhU507Kse+PSbsBJPUwKd1vG2bFsLmN0lDCQoQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://monkstudio.net

.
.
.

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Os files estão sendo gravados, como resolver?

*Link*: http://monkstudio.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua aplicação não esta criando sessão/cookie no browser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso a impede de validar o token. Não sei explicar o motivo exato mas já aconteceu comigo.

Para resolver isso, você precisa apontar a URL correta dentro do `.env` da aplicação no servidor.

Confira também o tipo de `SESSION` que esta atribuído no `.env`, se for `file`, precisa ter permissões de gravação no diretório `storage/sessions`.
Se for `database` precisa ter as migrations de sessão.

Leia sobre [isso aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xLjupiwxDrKRHrUseKw315QmXxWX64T4lb8WrT+GveA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://monkstudio.net

Comment: Apague seu comentário anterior, não passe sua APP_KEY para ninguém. Coloque assim `APP_URL=http://monkstudio.net`

Comment: Confira o `SESSION_DRIVER=file` e não esqueça de ver às permissões do diretório.

Comment: As sessões estão sendo gravadas porém não aparecem no navegador. BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

Comment: Faz um teste lá no config/session.php definindo lá a sessão forçadamente.

Comment: roda também um `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Cara, executei alguns comandos aqui,  php artisan key:generate ,  php artisan config:cache ,  php artisan auth:clear-resets    e voltou a funcionar.  Obrigado pela atenção